# Couldn't send cookies with AJAX cross-domain request in Phonegap

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, cookies, cross-domain

I have a server I'm trying to send cookies to. I send a first POST request, I store the received cookies from the response header and try with a second GET request to retrieve data an authenticated user could only access. The cross-domain request is okay, I'm able to retrieve my cookies within the Phonegap application, but when it comes to sending those, it fails. The request header does not contain any cookies. `phonegap -v` returns `5.1.1-0.29.0`.

What I've already tried:

- Add the domain to the whitelist
- Make sure the cookies I saved were not in the request headers, server side, at all
- Make the same request over C# to make sure it couldn't be a server side problem

The request code:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "url",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie", mycookies);
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    );
```

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, Phonegap does not appear to have any external plugin that can let you execute cross-domain AJAX calls with a `cookie` header. Silly. I have solved by writing a little proxy, couldn't get around with any other better solution. Thanks to whoever tried to help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

With quick search I understood Cordova doesn't hold cookies so you have to use Local Storage instead.

Here is example: http://justbuildsomething.com/cordova-and-express-session/

Comment: Read it already, the point is sending cookies, not storing them.

Comment: If Cordova can't store cookies you should add them to ajax call. Did you try Hanh Le suggestion? Should work.

Comment: Sharko, read it already. I've been looking around a lot lately, solved writing a little proxy. Thank you.

Comment: @ShinyPhoenix could you tell me how to use the proxy ? is there any cordova plugin that re send received cookies ?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add cookie in headers ajax:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "url",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
          Cookie: mycookies
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Where `Cookie: "test=test;"`, my simple PHP script `var_dump($_COOKIE);` returns `array(0)`. Nothing yet, then.